# How to benchmark my own script

Tags: python

I have a quite complex blender script and I would like to know if there is a way/tool to benchmark my script to find a possible bottleneck?
I have noticed that in some situations with many objects in different hierarchies my script takes around 2 to 3 min to finish the task and I would like to know where the bottleneck is.

On early test it seems like selecting and deleting a lot of empty objects takes time, but since this is just a perception I would like to know if I can track the time taken in specific parts of the code to know where the real bottleneck is.

Comment: can you post your script?

Comment: Since it contains some names that are under NDA I have to go through it and change them for some generic names so I can post the script.

Comment: Try to use `cProfile`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a general python question and thus better suited for stackoverflow.

Comment: I updated my question since this has been related with blender since beginning, maybe because I didn't mentioned Blender it seemed to be non-blender related.

Answer (score 3):

the easiest way might be to check the times:

```
import time

start = time.time()
print("your time consuming task")
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```