# Custom error message not working

Tags: python, add-on

I'm making a blender addon located on the N panel with some custom error messages. On the first button, I get the error message working properly, but in the second button is not working although it seems the structure is the same.

On the second button (the non-working one) if there is nothing selected then my error message should popup but is not working.
What could be causing it?

```
import bpy

structures_in_window = [
    {
        'name': 'WINDOWS',
        'items': [
            "frame-bnd-[!A-Z]*",
            "glass[!A-Z]*",
        ],
    },
]

class SelectByNameOperator_window(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Select objects by name"""
    bl_idname = "object.selected_by_name_operator_window"
    bl_label = "Select by Name"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        try:
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            for structure in structures_in_window:

                selection_pattern = bpy.ops.object.select_pattern
                
                for item in structure['items']:
                    selection_pattern(pattern = item)

                all_in_list = bpy.context.selected_objects.copy()
 
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
            
            
            objects = bpy.context.scene.objects.keys()
            if not 'WINDOW' in objects:
                print('There is no parent yet!!')

            elif 'WINDOW' in objects:
  
                ob = bpy.context.scene.objects["WINDOW"]
                bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob   
                ob.select_set(True)                          
                
        except IndexError:
                self.report({'ERROR'}, "Windows not found")

        return {'FINISHED'} 

class MYADDON_OT_my_op_move_to_existing_collection(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Move Selected to Existing Collection"""
    bl_label = "Move Selected to Existing Collection"
    bl_idname = "addonname.myop_operator_move_to_existing_collection"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        try:
            bpy.ops.object.move_to_collection('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
            
        except IndexError:
            if selection is None:
                self.report({'ERROR'}, "Why is not working")

        return {'FINISHED'}


class MYADDON_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Main Panel"
    bl_idname = "MYADDON_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "New Tab"


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        
        row=layout.row()
        scale_row = row.row()
        
        scale_row.scale_x = 0.7
        scale_row.label(text="Window", icon="OBJECT_DATA")
 
        scale_row.scale_x = 2.1
        scale_row.operator('object.selected_by_name_operator_window', text='', icon="RESTRICT_SELECT_OFF")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("addonname.myop_operator_move_to_existing_collection", icon="NLA_PUSHDOWN")


classes = [
            SelectByNameOperator_window,
            MYADDON_PT_main_panel,
            MYADDON_OT_my_op_move_to_existing_collection,
]


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        

 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Be explicit if you can and use `try, except` only if there is no way around it. In this case, you do not need any custom operator, just add `row.operator("object.move_to_collection", icon="NLA_PUSHDOWN")` to your draw method of the panel, see:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73548/31447 Notice that the `context` variable is passed to each method, replace `bpy.context.X` by `context.X`. Also, the name of the operator class should be something like `CATEGORY_OT_selectObject`, see: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons

Comment: To answer your question: You are trying to catch an `IndexError` which never being raised because you're not using an index operator like `my_list[10]` to return a certain entry from a list in your `try`-block. Recommend take a python course like: https://developers.google.com/edu/python will speed things up, you'll see.

Comment: As with your [previously closed question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222781/how-to-benchmark-my-own-script)  this one treads the line of being more about generic python syntax  than python specific to blender's API. IMO would be simpler to test for an empty list `if not context.selected_objects: continue` rather than catching an index error  on `context.selected_objects[0]`    As commented prior would seriously rethink using try-catch.